# $X_k$ are $\mathcal U(0,2\theta)$ distributed, and $Y_n=\max_{1\leq k < n}X_k$, how is $F_{Y_n}(t)=(\frac{t-\theta}{\theta})?$

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

$X_k$ are $\mathcal U(0,2\theta)$ distributed, and $Y_n=\max_{1\leq k < n}X_k$, how is $F_{Y_n}(t)=(\frac{t-\theta}{\theta}),\theta<t<2\theta\ \ ?$

$F_{Y_n}(t) \text{ aka }(CDF)$;
This does not seem intuitively correct and why is $t$ restricted to this interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed incorrect.

$F_{Y_n}(t) = P( \max_{i} X_i \leq t) = P(X_1,X_2, \dots X_n \leq t) $

Assuming $X_i$ are independent and not simply identically distributed:

$P(X_1,X_2, \dots X_n \leq t)  = \prod_i P(X_i \leq t) = (\frac{t}{2\theta})^n$ where $ 0 \leq t \leq 2\theta$

Thus,
$$
F_{Y_n}(t) = \begin{cases}
(\frac{t}{2\theta})^n & 0 \leq t \leq 2\theta\\
0 & t<0\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$